# how to allow only type in textarea digits, licenses, words what is in whitelist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How I can allow typing in textarea only allowed digital numbers of lenght or license codes or product codes with different lengths or specific words only..

I've done research but there is only blacklist for words what you cant type or codes what you cant type.

But I want to whitelist what you can type and what codes or product codes you can type in textarea.

Whitelist I can make with PHP so words, codes, licenses are in database.
And query them to javascript or jQuery.

Hardest part is JS or jQuery how to implement this.

Edit (allows only static codes and endings):

```
let values = event.target.value
        .split('\n')
        .map(v => {
          v = v.trim().toUpperCase();
          if (v.length <= 16) { // static only 16 digits long codes allowed
            if (CODE[0].substr(0, v.length) != v && // whitelist: const CODE = ["123456ASD", "654321DSA"];
              CODE[1].substr(0, v.length) != v) {
              v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1);
            }
          } else if (!v.substr(16, 22).match(reg)) { // static only 16 digits long and 6 digit long ending static
            v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1);
          }
          return v;
        }).join('\n');
```

I want create like non static and for universal product code list and word list or license code list..

Comment: In JS, you can add event listeners on "keydown" and "blur" (maybe some more) on that textarea which takes the data and validates it. You need to build the validation yourself though. Start with that and come back if you run into some specific issues with the code along the way. Then it's important that you post your attempt and explain the issue in detail. This question is unfortunately a bit too broad and unspecific at the moment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have code but its for static codes, words and lengths, it doesnt work well like universal. My code lets use example if have code "123456ASD" what is 9 digit long code its in whitelist and then code have ending with quantity 6 digit long "00012Q" - 12 is Quantity. Edited my post.

Comment: You need to show us the actual code you're having issues with (and any attempts you made) and we can take it from there. As mentioned, this question is currently too broad and unspecific. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Updated code and added where is static but I want like non static for Codes, Words or license codes. Product codes have endings with quantity, words doesnt have endings just whitelisted words what you can type, license codes "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" what you can type in textarea..